# how to update sqlite3 database in iphone

Tags: iphone, database

i want to update my sqlite database but i cannot find the way to do it,following is the code:

```
 const char *sqlStatement = "UPDATE frame SET fileExist = '1' WHERE name='$variable'";

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"successupdate");
}
```

from the above code i want my table update where the name is equal to $variable name;how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't believe a compiled statement can be compiled without specifying the table it applies to.  What are you trying to accomplish, exactly?  It's not quite clear to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're nearly there.

```
const char *sqlStatement = "UPDATE frame SET fileExist = '1' WHERE name=?";

sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);

sqlite3_bind_text(sqlStatement, 1, variable, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

int success = sqlite3_step(sqlStatement);

sqlite3_reset(sqlStatement);
```

Note that preparing the SQL statement only tells SQLite what the statement looks like. It's `sqlite3_bind_text` that applies the variable to the SQL statement and the `sqlite3_step` line that actually *runs* it.

Answer (score 0):

[FMDB](http://gusmueller.com/blog/archives/2008/03/fmdb_for_iphone.html) is a nice wrapper for SQLite statements.  It takes care of most of the prepare/bind/step/reset drudgery.  I highly recommend it for any project that needs a DB, but doesn't want to use Core Data.